# How to add also a text link to this jQuery toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle

I have a jQuery toggle link designed to look like a button. When pressed by the user it toggles and shows the `div` below.

Now I would like to add some text like "More" next to the link that will act in the same way as if the link is pressed - show the content when pressed once and hide it when pressed again. In the same time I would like to keep the original functionality of the first link.

I have tried several possibilities but cannot get it to work properly, any suggestions will be appreciated.

This is the function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   $(".slidingDiv").hide();
   $(".show_hide_search").show();

   $('.show_hide_search').on('click', function(e){
       e.preventDefault();

       var self    = this,
           sliding = $(this).closest('div').next('.slidingDiv').slideToggle(function(){
               $(self).text(function(_,txt) {
                    return txt == "–" ? "+" : "–";
               });
           });
    });
});
```

And here is the HTML:

```
<div>
    <a href="#" class="show_hide_search" id="plus">+</a>    
    <div style="margin-left:30px;" class="show_hide_search2">More</div>
</div>
```

Here's a full test:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

   $(".slidingDiv").hide();
   $(".show_hide_search").show();

   $('.show_hide_search').on('click', function(e){
       e.preventDefault();

       var self    = this,
           sliding = $(this).closest('div').next('.slidingDiv').slideToggle(function(){
               $(self).text(function(_,txt) {
                    return txt == "–" ? "+" : "–";
               });
           });
    });
});
```

```css
.show_hide_search {
  font: bold 14px Arial;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: orange;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  padding: 2px 6px 1px 6px;  
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -khtml-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;        
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
        <a href="#" class="show_hide_search" id="plus">+</a>    
        <div style="margin-left:30px;" class="show_hide_search2">More</div>
    </div>  

    <div class="slidingDiv" style="display: block;">
          <h2>Content One</h2>
    </div>

    <div>
        <a href="#" class="show_hide_search" id="plus">+</a>
        <div style=" margin-left:30px;" class="show_hide_search2">More</div>
    </div>  

    <div class="slidingDiv" style="display: block;">
          <h2>Content Two</h2>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the onclick listener to the container instead.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   $(".slidingDiv").hide();
   $(".show_hide_search").show();

   $('.show_hide_toggle').on('click', function(e){
       e.preventDefault();

       var self    = this,
           sliding = $(this).closest('div').next('.slidingDiv').slideToggle(function(){
               $($(self).children()[0]).text(function(_,txt) {
                    return txt == "–" ? "+" : "–";
               });
           });
    });
});
```

Check it out here: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eBfxB/7/)

Comment: This works great caeth! Thank you for the solution. Would you be able to also suggest a way to remember the state of each toggle link in a session variable?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/eBfxB/4/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   $(".slidingDiv").hide();
   $(".show_hide_search").show();

   $('.show_hide_search').on('click', function(e){
       e.preventDefault();

       var self    = this,
           sliding = $(this).closest('div').next('.slidingDiv').slideToggle(function(){
               $(self).text(function(_,txt) {
                    return txt == "–" ? "+" : "–";
               });
           });
    });
    
    
    $('.show_hide_search2').on('click', function(e){
        console.log(123)
       e.preventDefault();

       var self    = this,
           sliding = $(this).closest('.slideButtons').nextAll('.slidingDiv').first().slideToggle();
    });
        
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="slideButtons">
    <a href="#" class="show_hide_search" id="plus">+</a>    
    <div style="margin-left:30px;" class="show_hide_search2">More</div>
</div>  

<div class="slidingDiv" style="display: block;">
      <h2>Content One</h2>
</div>

<div class="slideButtons">
    <a href="#" class="show_hide_search" id="plus">+</a>
    <div style=" margin-left:30px;" class="show_hide_search2">More</div>
</div>  

<div class="slidingDiv" style="display: block;">
      <h2>Content Two</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: That works great, thanks for the Demo also! Btw, can you also suggest a way to remember the stare .show or .hide in a session variable?

Comment: I missed that the `+` is not changing to `-` when More is pressed so checked another answer that does that.

Answer (score 0):

Using the class `show_hide_search2` and forcing the `.prev()` to `click()`:

```
$('.show_hide_search2').click(function(){
    $(this).prev().click();
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

   $(".slidingDiv").hide();
   $(".show_hide_search").show();

   $('.show_hide_search').on('click', function(e){
       e.preventDefault();

       var self    = this,
           sliding = $(this).closest('div').next('.slidingDiv').slideToggle(function(){
               $(self).text(function(_,txt) {
                    return txt == "–" ? "+" : "–";
               });
           });
    });
  $('.show_hide_search2').click(function(){
    $(this).prev().click();
  });
});
```

```css
.show_hide_search {
  font: bold 14px Arial;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: orange;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  padding: 2px 6px 1px 6px;  
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -khtml-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;        
}
.show_hide_search2 {
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
        <a href="#" class="show_hide_search" id="plus">+</a>    
        <div style="margin-left:30px;" class="show_hide_search2">More</div>
    </div>  

    <div class="slidingDiv" style="display: block;">
          <h2>Content One</h2>
    </div>

    <div>
        <a href="#" class="show_hide_search" id="plus">+</a>
        <div style=" margin-left:30px;" class="show_hide_search2">More</div>
    </div>  

    <div class="slidingDiv" style="display: block;">
          <h2>Content Two</h2>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

html

```
<!-- add `show_hide_search` class to `div` containing "More" text 
     remove `style` attribute , add style at css
-->
<div> <a href="#" class="show_hide_search" id="plus">+</a> 
<div class="show_hide_search show_hide_search2">More</div>
</div>
<div class="slidingDiv" style="display: block;">
     <h2>Content One</h2>

</div>
<div> <a href="#" class="show_hide_search" id="plus">+</a>

    <div class="show_hide_search show_hide_search2">More</div>
</div>
<div class="slidingDiv" style="display: block;">
     <h2>Content Two</h2>

</div>
```

css

```
/* add `:not(div)` to negate styles for div containing "More" text , 
   `margin-left` style for div containing "More" 
*/
.show_hide_search:not(div) {
  font: bold 14px Arial;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: orange;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  padding: 2px 6px 1px 6px;  
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -khtml-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;      
}
div.show_hide_search {
  margin-left : 30px;
}
```

js

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(".slidingDiv").hide();
    $(".show_hide_search").show();

    $('.show_hide_search').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var self = this,
            sliding = $(this)
            // add `:not(.show_hide_search)` to negate `div` containing "More"
           .closest('div:not(.show_hide_search)')
           .next('.slidingDiv')
           .slideToggle(function () {
                // add `.not(div)` to negate `div` containing "More"
                $(self).not("div").text(function (_, txt) {
                    return txt == "–" ? "+" : "–";
                });
            });
    });
});
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/eBfxB/9/

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(".slidingDiv").hide();
    $(".show_hide_search").show();

    $('.show_hide_search').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var self = this,
            sliding = $(this).closest('div:not(.show_hide_search)').next('.slidingDiv').slideToggle(function () {
                $(self).not("div").text(function (_, txt) {
                    return txt == "–" ? "+" : "–";
                });
            });
    });
});
```

```css
.show_hide_search:not(div) {
    font: bold 14px Arial;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: orange;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    padding: 2px 6px 1px 6px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

div.show_hide_search {
    margin-left : 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div> <a href="#" class="show_hide_search" id="plus">+</a> 
    <div class="show_hide_search show_hide_search2">More</div>
</div>
<div class="slidingDiv" style="display: block;">
     <h2>Content One</h2>

</div>
<div> <a href="#" class="show_hide_search" id="plus">+</a>

    <div class="show_hide_search show_hide_search2">More</div>
</div>
<div class="slidingDiv" style="display: block;">
     <h2>Content Two</h2>

</div>
```